# SFDC - passing inputs to URLFOR

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I'm currently trying to customize an object on Salesforce and need to create a action button that will lead to a new account edit page.

I would like to prefill the new account page by passing inputs through the URLFOR function (see below); in my example, the parameter value is not interpreted.

```
<apex:page>
  <apex:outputLink value="{! URLFOR( $Action.Account.New, null, [acc2='{! Object__c.Name}'] ) }">New Account</apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to pass variables inputs through URLFOR in apex ?

Thanks for your help.

Crak

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are using the URLFOR function correctly.

Using

```
<apex:outputLink value="{! URLFOR( $Action.Account.New, null, [acc2='Acme'] ) }">New Account</apex:outputLink>
```

I was able to have a account screen load with Acme as the account name.

I believe the problem is that your call to get the name is returning null or blank so it appears that it is not applying anything to the Name field.

In your controller you should have a property that gives you access to the working record. Get the name like the following example.

Controller

```
Object__c MyCustomObject {get;set;}
```

Page

```
<apex:outputLink value="{! URLFOR( $Action.Account.New, null, [acc2=MyCustomObject.Name] ) }">New Account</apex:outputLink>
```

*If that doesnt work as is, try changing to [acc2='MyCustomObject.Name'] etc*

Answer (score 0):

To get more generic solution you can use:
$Action.Account[] 
when actionName is string variable(from apexclass or custom setting) can be:
View: Shows the detail page of an object
Edit: Shows the object in Edit mode
Delete: URL for deleting an object
New: URL to create a new record of an object
Tab: URL to the home page of an object

We can do it even more generic by change the object name to a variable too

$Action[objectName][actionName]

for example:
VFP:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="urlForParamCTRL"
           action="{!urlFor($Action[objectName][actionName],account.Id, null, true)}">
</apex:page>
```

Apex class:

```
public class urlForParamCTRL {
    Public String objectName {get;set;}
    Public String actionName {get;set;}
    public urlForParamCTRL(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.objectName = 'Account';
        this.actionName = 'New';
    }
}
```

reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_action.htm